# How to Transfer Big Data to a Different Domain

Tags: joomla, import, export, backups

I received a SQL error while updating CiviCRM. He asked me to restore the old database, but I didn't have a backup at the time. Therefore I could not make a healthy update. Then I applied all the updates, but I still get "Database Partially Upgraded - Database check failed" warning for the database.

I have very serious data. I don't want anything to happen to this data.

So I thought of something like this. I'm going to build a new Joomla - CiviCRM. In my setup, I will rebuild all the fields as in the old site. Then I will import the data from the old domain.

But here's the thing. There are more than 130000 activities. It is not possible to transfer such data in bulk. It is not even possible to get 100 pieces because it gives a constant error.

Here are the data I'm trying to get.

Contact ID, Contact Type, Sort Name, Display Name, Contact Source, Contact Hash, First Name, Last Name, Email Greeting ID, Postal Greeting ID, Addressee ID, Created Date, Modified Date, Addressee, Phone, Phone Type, Activity ID , Activity Type, Activity Type ID, Subject, Activity Date, Duration, Details, Activity Status, Activity Priority, Source Contact, Source Contact ID.
I also have custom fields that I have created for Activity Types.

How can I transfer all this without problems.

Comment: Does the old site run at all? Could you do something like write a script to use the api to transfer all the contacts over and then the activities?

Comment: It sounds like if you could explain the problems you are hitting with the upgrade eg on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/ then someone could help you get out of the problem without rebuilding, or data transfers.

Comment: Hi  Demerit; Old ste is working. I'm processing but I don't know how to create an API.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "big dump"to move big databases ozerov.de/bigdump/ with good success

Comment: The topic here is not to move the database directly to a different location. To retrieve the information I requested in the database.