# CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: constraint violation"

Tags: joomla

Under [How to Transfer Big Data to a Different Domain](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31636/how-to-transfer-big-data-to-a-different-domain), I asked a question about transferring data to a different domain, but I couldn't find a solution. Before writing a comment, please read the information I have provided here. So I tried to implement my own solution. However, according to my mistake, my own solution steps did not work.

---

Namely;

I installed a joomla and CiviCRM from scratch. I didn't make any customization and updates in my installation.

Then I threw the following tables and all log tables into new SQL. I have not encountered any errors in this transfer. (I transferred by typing _bacup next to the existing table names to avoid conflicts.)

1. civicrm_activity
2. civicrm_activity
3. civicrm_activity_contact
4. civicrm_contact
5. civicrm_custom_field
6. civicrm_custom_group
7. civicrm_email
8. civicrm_log
9. civicrm_option_group
10. civicrm_option_value
11. civicrm_phone
12. civicrm_setting
13. civicrm_uf_match
14. joomla_usergroups
15. joomla_users
16. joomla_user_usergroup_map

Now when I try to log in to CiviCRM I get an error like the following. Do you know about the solution to this error?

**CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: constraint violation"**

Comment: To get more information about the error. You can run the api from the API explorer and check the box debug. You will probably then get a backtrace of where in the api the error occurs.

Comment: How do I access the API when I can't log in to CiviCRM?

Comment: Ah than you are stuck because I made the assumption you could login into civicrm and just one specific api is causing a trouble. But that is not the case. This still sound you did not do the import/backup correctly.

Comment: There's serious data. CiviCRM gives an error because the export and import data from their menu is large. I can't update. I need to get these files to a clean CiviCRM. So when I make a transfer, which tables do I need to import from the database?

Comment: A rule of thumb is that you need all of them. And you dont usually have to do a transfer (or I have not come in such situations where it is really needed).

Comment: Thank you Jaap Jansma for your answers worker. However I have a problem with the Update. And I believe that this issue will be a big problem in a future update.

I'm starting an update when a new CiviCRM version arrives. At the end of the transaction

The Error version I received was 5.14.1. We are currently using 5.19.1. When I update, I see version 5.19.1 at the bottom, but in the System State, the "Partially upgraded database" gives a critical error.

Therefore, I believe that either this problem should be solved or a current CiviCRM installation should be transferred to my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share my solution for the problem. First of all, I did this because of a partially loaded database problem. I was getting this error when I did any CiviCRM version upgrade.

When I checked the database, the information in the "civicrm_domain" table was displayed as "5.14.alpha1.upgrade". However, because the site was an FTP update CiviCRM version 5.19.1 was.

First of all, I set up a backup of a time before 5.14 with a different subdomain. Then I upgraded the Joomla and CiviCRM version of this backup to the version I had problems, ie 5.14.1.

Then I deleted everything in the database, including Joomla tables. I have thrown the SQL files with the actual site data into the SQL files of the new subdomain. In the "civicrm_domain" table, I manually changed the version information to "5.14.1".

After that I started the update with the URL of CiviCRM 5.15.0 in Joomla Plugin Update and this time I didn't get "partially loaded database" error and the whole update was successful.

The only problem is that any update, installation and uninstallation of the CiviCRM plug-ins is displayed. I have raised a question for this error. You can also follow it if you want. Of course, that problem will be corrected.