# CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "API error: DB Error: already exists"

Tags: extension, joomla, error, install

[CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: constraint violation"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33765/civicrm-api3-exception-db-error-constraint-violation) I have fixed these problem by updating one by one from 5.14.1 to 5.19.1 but now I have got new problem :) In the new version I cant install/uninstall and update any extention. I got the following error on screen:

[image]

But I realised when I click back than is the update or install/uninstall is done. But everytime when I try I get the same error. Anybody who knows the reason of the error showing ?

Comment: Based on the other post there could be multiple problems, but if you have CiviCase enabled then this might be the same as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/329 which can happen if the site is non-english. If so, that will be fixed in 5.20.

Comment: Hi Demerit. I use the system in Turkish language. I did the language in English, then I disabled CiviCase. Caches and Update Paths cleaned up. I received no errors when I update, uninstall, or install any plug-ins. Then the Turkish language investment. I didn't get the error again. Finally I've activated CiviCase. When I checked, I saw that the error continued in the same way. Is this a problem with the CiviCase?

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the comments:

Sorry I don't speak Turkish but I put your comment into Bing translate and the short answer is "yes". The error happens when you have **changed a relationship type** (which happens automatically if you change the language) and you're using CiviCase in non-english. So the temporary options are:

- Disable civicase or only use english. (Not the best option.)
- Put the relationship type back to the english version. (Also not good.)
- If you don't have many relationships entered yet you can delete all the relationships, delete the relationship type and recreate a new one, then update your case types, then add your relationships again.
- Wait until 5.20.

Comment: Sorry. As a result of a thoughtfulness I wrote in Turkish. I just updated the comment in English. :)

Comment: There are over 400 thousand events. Updating them and using the language in English are not suitable for me. It's best to wait at 5.20. :)

Comment: Did you try disabling the standard core case types? If you are lucky that might fix the immediate DB error showing up.....

Comment: Hi Erik. I made the language again in English to implement the proposal. Disable Medical Examination, Mental Health Examination, Safe Temporary Shelter, Income and Benefit Balance,
Long Term Shelter Plan
I have disabled the standardized case types. Other than these cannot be disabled already. Then I activated the CiviCase component. I did the Cleanup Caches and Update Paths and I got the same error when I tried. So did not solve the problem. So I get this error as long as CiviCase is active.